# Physics body leaving circle player

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicsbody

My issue is similar to this questions ([physics body not inline with shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869574/physics-body-not-inline-with-shape)) except setting the center doesn't help. I've played around with it a bunch but I can't get the physics body to stay wrapped about the circle.

First issue in the [first video](https://estit.github.io/images/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif). 
Similar/new problem in [second video](https://estit.github.io/images/ezgif.com-video-to-gif%20(1).gif)

Here's my code for set up:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "smileyEmoji")
sprite.size = CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)
sprite.name = "player"
sprite.zPosition = 3

player.addChild(sprite)
player.position = CGPoint(x:85, y:140)
player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.7
player.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0

player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CollisionCategoryPlayer
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CollisionCategoryPlatform | PhysicsCategory.CollisionCategoryPoint
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  PhysicsCategory.CollisionCategoryPoint | PhysicsCategory.CollisionCategoryDevil
```

After springing:

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (self.player.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode).size.width/2, center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.0))
player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

Comment: Why not set the SKPhysicsbody(circleOfRadius) before emoji is launched? Try setting it before all of the "player.physicsBody" properties.

Comment: @Muffinman2497 I tried that and that's what the first video shows. For some reason the slide to pull back the emoji moves the emoji but leaves its physics body unmoved. The slide function is just changing `player.position`